# Django Application - Development/Update methods

Tags: django, software-distribution

I have an application written in Django that has now become quite sizeable, the application is in constant use throughout the day and making changes 'on-the-fly' risks disruption.

I am fairly new to software development and am not sure what the best way is to develop a django application where I can issue updates grouped together and release a 'version'. So instead of me updating the main application as and when in a live environment, I'd like if I can have a development server where I can develop & test any updates and then I can roll these out once a month.

I can just copy the view/model files over and overwrite the old ones but what is the best way to handle database changes? I assume I will have to write SQL to add/drop changed columns and overwrite the django_content_type table completely?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go further than Ashish: you *must* use version control. You should not be "copying files over" and overwriting old ones. In 2014 there is no excuse for not using something like git (or Mercurial, or even SVN).

For the database changes, you should of course be using migrations. In version 1.7, due to be released very soon now, these are included in core Django. In previous versions, you will need to install the third-party library South.

Comment: Absolutely. You "must" use version control, rather than "can". You owe it to your users.

Answer (score 0):

As for the source files, you can use `git`. You test your changes on a dev (or test) server, and once you're satisfied, push the changes to git. On the prod server, you then pull the changes and restart server.

The database changes can be accomplished using `south` and migrations. Again, you need to test your migrations on dev or test before pushing them to git. Once you're satisfied, you can then move the changes to prod.

The flow is ...

```
develop --> test --> commit changes to remote git --> pull changes on production --> migrate --> restart server
```

Look here for important links

- git --> http://git-scm.com
- githut --> http://github.com
- south --> http://south.aeracode.org/

Comment: Only concern is my code isn't intended to be public/open source. Is it advisable to put private code on such services - call me paranoid but what if it gets stolen.

Comment: You can have a private git repo on github (it'll cost you a monthly membership) or bitbucket (it's free). South is a local install. If it's company code, then it obviously depends on your corporate policy.